# How to do this lookup operation in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

There are two sheets (sheet1 & sheet2) in my Excel file, it's like daily work routine (entry date, pickup date, dispatch date). Some details will change as per the work flow and even new entries will appear.

I just need to compare both files if a change occurred in one cell it must have to show entire row of sheet1 (I can't specify exact headline for that all details are too precious and it has more than 100 headlines).

So if there is any formula for that please let me know like

```
IF+VLOOKUP
```

please correct below given formula

```
=If(RECHERCHEV(A2,sheet1!A8:FM264,1,FAUX)=(RECHERCHEV(A2,sheet2!A8:FM257,1,FAUX);"";RECHERCHEV(A2,sheet1!A8:FM264,1,FAUX))
```

It's the French version.

Comment: 1. Your title should describe your problem, not be a general plea. 2. Format your code by highlighting it and press ctrl+k while editing.

Comment: Also this site is run by volunteers answering questions so requesting "urgent help" will not actually help you.

Comment: Also someone beat me to editing it but please don't write run-on sentences and use proper punctuation. Your question was really hard to read

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please verify [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and then please edit your question.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?  If you have version >= 2010, you can use `Conditional Formatting` to do the comparison.  Here is something for your reference (http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/09/03/conditional-formatting-from-different-sheet/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula in cell A1 of sheet3 and drag across and down.

> =IF(AND(EXACT(Sheet1!1:1,Sheet2!1:1)),"",Sheet1!A1)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're looking to do here, and I don't speak french, but it looks like you have an extra parenthesis before your 2nd RECHERCHEV function.

Try this :

```
=If(RECHERCHEV(A2,sheet1!A8:FM264,1,FAUX)=RECHERCHEV(A2,sheet2!A8:FM257,1,FAUX);"";RECHERCHEV(A2,sheet1!A8:FM264,1,FAUX))
```

Though I'm not sure why the IF function uses semi-colons, but the RECHERCHEV uses commas, so maybe this:

```
=If(RECHERCHEV(A2,sheet1!A8:FM264,1,FAUX)=RECHERCHEV(A2,sheet2!A8:FM257,1,FAUX),"",RECHERCHEV(A2,sheet1!A8:FM264,1,FAUX))
```

Also it seems you want the entire row to update, so I am not sure how this vlookup would work since the arrays start in different rows than the lookup value.

Comment: I believe `VLOOKUP()` is equal to `RECHERCHEV()`.